# How to resolve caste issue using mongoose reference?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have issue with referencing `User` with template model, I am trying to save template data but it is throwing cast to object id fail, I am new to mongoose any help will be appreciated.

templateModel.js

```
var User = require('../user/user.model.js');

var TemplateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  id: String,
  appliesTo: [],
  properties: [],
  createdBy: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
 });


export default mongoose.model('Template', TemplateSchema);
```

userModel.js

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true, index: {unique: true}},
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  type: String,
  groups:[{type: String, ref: 'Group', required: false}]
},
  {
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true
    }
  });

UserSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function() {
  return this.firstName+' '+this.lastName;
});

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Client side object printing on server side

```
{
    name: 'Java Class',
    id: 'javaClass',
    appliesTo: ['bpmn:ServiceTask'],
    properties: [{
        label: 'Java Package Name',
        type: 'String',
        editable: true,
        binding: [Object]
    }],
    createdBy: 'sh829'
}
```

MongoDb Error

```
{
    "errors": {
        "createdBy": {
            "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"sh829\" at path \"createdBy\"",
            "name": "CastError",
            "stringValue": "\"sh829\"",
            "kind": "ObjectID",
            "value": "sh829",
            "path": "createdBy",
            "reason": {
                "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"sh829\" at path \"createdBy\"",
                "name": "CastError",
                "stringValue": "\"sh829\"",
                "kind": "ObjectId",
                "value": "sh829",
                "path": "createdBy"
            }
        }
    },
    "message": "Template validation failed",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Comment: `createdBy` has an invalid value, it should has `ObjectId` value, something like that `4cdfb11e1f3c000000007822`.

Comment: thats how _id is saved in `User` collection, basically current user that is logged in to application will be user and fill the createdBy field for templateSchema

Comment: Any `User` document has `_id` field with this value? Are you sure?

Comment: yup 100% positive

Comment: show `User` model declaration.

Comment: user model added to question

Comment: Why did you add `_id` filed in `User` model declaration? This field is auto generated and added to each model by default. If you want to have own id, declare it as `id` and remove relation to `User` from `Template`.

Comment: okay then how we will reference the User for template if we remove relation

Comment: If you want leave the relation, then just remove own `_id` field and use auto generated.

Comment: Thank you for the help i got it.